# Surgical vs anatomical neck

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology

What is the significance of differentiating anatomical neck and surgical neck of a bone?

What could be criterias for differentiation?

I found an article [here](https://www2.aofoundation.org/wps/portal/surgerypopup?contentUrl=/srg/popup/further_reading/PFxM2/11/621_2_surg_anat.jsp) that says fractures to surgical neck are benign, could this be a criteria for differentiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, I have heard this differentiation in context of Humerus bone only. In that context, have a look at the wiki pages on the [anatomical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_neck_of_humerus) and the [surgical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surgical_neck_of_the_humerus) necks.

From this, and what I remember from anatomy class, this distinction is more a *functional; practical* distinction rather than that based on strictly defined criteria. Surgical neck denotes the **most commonly fractured region** of the bone, and also the region **most likely to damage the axillary nerve** passing nearby, and hence would have the greatest representation in an orthopedic clinic. The anatomical neck, on the other end, is the classical distinction based on the **centers of ossification** and the **insertion of the capsular ligament of the adjacent shoulder joint**, which gives a greater weightage to its origin and to the anatomical relations (insertions, etc).